# Floor Generator (planks.py), ProWood and Light From a Sun Light

Tags: cycles-render-engine, add-on

When I use [ProWood](https://www.blendermarket.com/products/prowood-procedural-wood-shader-pack) for [planks](https://github.com/varkenvarken/blenderaddons/blob/master/planks.py) and a sun every single (planar) plank is showing me where the light is coming from. Is there a way to turn this off??

[image]
[image]

Comment: That looks like shading problem not related with material. Try either using Bevel modifier ot adding EdgeSplit modifier (or Autosmooth option) to the planks.

Comment: Great, that's the reason! Floor generator does __NOT__ generate planks using flat shading. Thank you.